# GSM Modem for linux

Tags: linux, modem, gsm

I am looking for a GSM modem capable of sending SMS to be used in CentOS 5.3.
In the other word, how can I make sure if a specific modem can be detected on kernel 2.6 before buying it.

Comment: As long as it presents itself to the system as a serial device and speaks AT commands, it *should* work.

Comment: Since CentOS is derived from RHEL you could try the [hardware compatibility](https://hardware.redhat.com/) list

Answer (score 2):

My employee are using a GSM modem called: HT910G
We are running it on our OP5 system and works great with CentOS 6.x and Linux 2.6

Here's the manual: https://kb.op5.com/download/attachments/6193522/Technical%20Description%20HT910%20G%201.1.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1395759338000&api=v2

When we migrated the system from bare metal to VMware we hooked the GSM modems up to a "Moxa" which converts TCP/IP to Serial (Could maybe be useful info)

Here's the Moxa: http://www.moxa.com/product/nport_5110.htm

Answer (score -1):

I use:

```
Manufacturer : Cinterion
Model        : MC52i
Product name : MC52i
Revision     : REVISION 01.201
```

It is connected via COM port and REQUIRES external power supply.

Having some problems with it though - sometimes it doesn't send sms with error code 11, but it might be related to the service provider (vodafone).

If I was selecting a new one, I would go for something to USB, but I found that very difficult to find any working. For example - I was testing Vodafone K5150 and I wasn't able to switch it to tty/USB device under linux. It showed only as a network card. It was able to send sms in windows though.